# Videos stored on Amazon S3 of lower quality when downloaded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm building a web application that allows people to download videos from my site that's stored in Amazon S3. It's going great so far, save for the fact that when I download the video stored in S3, it appears to be slightly more pixelated and fuzzy than the same video that has not been uploaded. The videos are in mp4 format and around 150 mb big. I upload them using S3's web uploader. Does anybody know what is going on and how to fix this? I want my customers to have the best quality possible.

Comment: I dont think S3 does anything with the content of the uploaded object, this sounds more like internet connection issue, the best way to validate it is to check the parameters of video you have uploaded and compare that with the streaming video

Comment: @MehulRathod Now that you said something, the file downloaded from S3 is larger in size by 27mb for some reason. I'm baffled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 shouldnt do anything to the video quality. Perhaps it is the player you're using? Perhaps try a different flash player like JW Player, as the only possible reasons (i can think of) the quality would be going down is either due to the flash player or the actual embedding of the video.

Comment: Finally found the problem. When I initially downloaded it, I paused it and then restarted it. Now when I download it regular, it comes in the same size and quality. Have a green checkmark, cheers!